# MySQL select query, retrieve data from more than one column by typing more than one word in search bar

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, here's the deal, I have a database let's say with 2 columns:
"name" and "lastname"

When I type in a input box a name like "John" it would retrieve all John's from the "name" column. When I type in a lastname like "Doe" it would retrieve all Doe's from the "lastname" column. This works as expected.

But I would like it to also retrieve data from both columns when i type in "John Doe", so it would return all John Doe's. When typing one word in the searchbar, it works alright, but when i put in another word after space, it does not do what I want, coz I don't kno how should i form the query right.

Here's the code of query.php:

```php
    <?php
    require_once("config.php");
    // Fetch the data
    $searchbar = $_POST['searchbar'];

    $querymilion = "SELECT * from lms.customers where `lastname` LIKE '%$searchbar%' OR `name` LIKE '%$searchbar%'";
    mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
    $resultmilion = @mysql_query($querymilion);

    // Return the results, loop through them and echo
    if($fraza) {
    while($rowmilion = mysql_fetch_array($resultmilion))
    {
    ?>
    <a href="javascript:klientid()" onClick="klientid()">
    <table id="tablesz" >
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; width: 160px; text-align:right;">ID:</td>
    <td style="width:200px;" id="getidfromsearch"><?php echo $rowmilion['id']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; width: 50px; text-align:right;">PESEL:</td>
    <td style="width:200px;"><?php echo $rowmilion['ssn']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;width: 160px; text-align:right;">Nazwisko i Imię:</td>
    <td style="width:200px;"><?php echo $rowmilion['lastname']; ?> <?php echo   $rowmilion['name']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold;width: 50px; text-align:right;">Dow.os.:</td>
    <td style="width:200px;"><?php echo $rowmilion['icn']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; width: 160px; text-align:right;">Adres instalacji</td>
    <td style="width:200px;"><?php echo $rowmilion['address']; ?></td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold; width: 50px; text-align:right;">Miasto:</td>
    <td style="width:200px;"><?php echo $rowmilion['zip']; ?> <?php echo $rowmilion['city']; ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </a>
    <?php

    }
    }
    ?>
```

And here's the searchbar:

```php
    <div id="szukaj">
    <table id="tablesz" >
    <tr>
<td class="naglowek">Szukaj klienta</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="query.php" method="post"  name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="searchbar" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Szukaj" /> 
</form>
</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>
<span id="error"></span>
<span id="result"></span>
</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: what do you mean by type another word in search box?

Comment: @RaheelShan, I meant if i type more than one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `actor` 
WHERE CONCAT( firstname,  ' ', lastname ) LIKE  "%$searchbar%"
```

This can become very slow when your table increases. But it works.
If you also want to have the possibility to switch the order of firstname lastname to lastname firstname, just add this to the Query:

```
OR CONCAT( lastname,  ' ', firstname ) LIKE  "%$searchbar%"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your CODE,

if you want to make a searh like `John Doe` you need to separate each word and put it into the lie, of course it will decrease the speed of the query.

I.E:

```
$querymilion = "SELECT * from lms.customers 
where (`lastname` LIKE '%$John%' OR `name` LIKE '%$John%')
and (`lastname` LIKE '%$Doe%' OR `name` LIKE '%$Doe%')";
```

this will give you the exact match with `John Doe`.